# How do I attach two separate callbacks to a Twisted deferred, so both fire after the result is ready?

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, deferred

I am not very experienced with Twisted, but here is what I understand so far.
When I do a database query such as:

```
db = database.veryLongQuery(sql, binds)
```

I can add callbacks to do something with the result,

```
db.addCallback(lambda res: dispalyResult(res))
```

Otherwise if I need to do multiple things to the same result, I could make a method:

```
def doTwoThings(self, res):
    self.d1 = anotherDeferred(res) # write to table A, return lastRowId
    self.d2 = yetAnotherDeferred(res) # write to table B, return lastRowId
    return d1
```

and attach that to `db` (as the first callback)

```
db.addCallback(self.doTwoThings)
```

However, I would like to have a reference to `d1` and `d2` right from the start, at the same time as when db is created, since other events will be happening and I need to add callbacks to `d1` and `d2`.

How would I go about attaching two (or more) separate callback chains onto the same deferred, `db`, so it 'splits', and both are fired side by side once the result is ready?

This way I can keep track of each deferred from the start and access them as necessary.

Or, is there way to create `d1` and `d2` from the start, so I have access to those names?

Comment: It's always possible to just have one custom callback function that does nothing but call your two other functions.  I can't really tell what you're trying to do and don't know your environment, but any promise/deferred capability I know allows you to have as many done handlers as you want.

Comment: Basically I'm writing to a database with a surrogate (row id) primary key. When other events arrive which I also want to write to the database, I must wait for the original write to finish and return the row id/key because that will be the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
def splitResults(d1, d2):
    def splitter(val):
        # Pass val to d2 chain
        d2.callback(val)
        # Return val into d1's chain
        return val

    def splitterError(err):
        d2.errback(err)
    d1.addCallbacks(splitter, splitterError)
```

So, whenever d1 gets result, it will pass it to d2 too.

Comment: This is part of an implementation.  You forgot about error handling, though.

Comment: Thank you, this works. For error handling, is adding errbacks to d1 and d2 enough?   When val is a failure, it would just return the failure to the next callback.